# Error in Handlebars template - Parse error when using conditional statements

Tags: node.js, express, handlebars.js, express-handlebars

I'm currently working on a web application using Node.js and Express, and I'm using the Handlebars template engine to render my views. I have a route that displays a list of students with pagination, and I'm encountering a parse error in my Handlebars template.

**Here's my Express route:**

```
app.get('/student-list', async (req, res) => {
    // Retrieve a list of all students from your data source
    let allStudents = await business.getAllStudents();

    // Implement pagination logic to group students into pages of 6
    const page = parseInt(req.query.page) || 1; // Get the requested page number from the query parameter
    const perPage = 6;
    const startIndex = (page - 1) * perPage;
    const endIndex = startIndex + perPage;
    const studentsToDisplay = allStudents.slice(startIndex, endIndex);

    // Calculate the total number of pages
    const totalPages = Math.ceil(allStudents.length / perPage);

    res.render('student_list', {
        studentsList: studentsToDisplay,
        currentPage: page,
        totalPages: totalPages
    });
});
```

**And here's my student_list.hbs template:**

```
<body>
    <h1>Student List</h1>
    {{#each studentsList}}
    <div>
        <p>{{this.name}}</p>
        <!-- Display other student details here -->
    </div>
    {{/each}}

    <!-- Pagination Links -->
    <div class="pagination">
        {{#if currentPage > 1}}
            <a href="/student-list?page={{currentPage-1}}">Previous</a>
        {{/if}}
        {{#if currentPage < totalPages}}
            <a href="/student-list?page={{currentPage+1}}">Next</a>
        {{/if}}
    </div>
</body>
```

**I'm getting the following error when rendering this template:**

```
Error: Parse error on line 13:
...  {{#if currentPage > 1}}
            <
-----------------------^
Expecting 'CLOSE_RAW_BLOCK', 'CLOSE', 'CLOSE_UNESCAPED', 'OPEN_SEXPR', 'CLOSE_SEXPR', 'ID', 'EQUALS', 'OPEN_BLOCK_PARAMS', 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'BOOLEAN',
```

Comment: Handlebars does not support logical operators like `>`. You would need to create a custom helper (or include one that someone else has created) to allow you to do a _greater than_ comparison.